# Why do M4 guns appear in Stranger Things?

Tags: stranger-things

Well, as we know Stranger Things is in the 80s (not later than 1984). The gun in those scene looks exactly like the M4 model while the M4 is in service in 1994.

[image: m4]

[image: m4_2]

Is this a mistake or I take it wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Inconclusive

The pictures you've provided are dreadfully unclear, so it's impossible to tell if we're actually looking at an [M4 carbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_carbine) as claimed.

The "Internet Movie Firearms Database" believes they are [Colt Model 723](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Stranger_Things_-_Season_2#Colt_Model_723), which is a variation of the [M16A2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR-15#M4_Carbine), the same weapon the M4 Carbine is based on. The M16A2 was officially adopted by US Department of Defense in 1982, for use by the US Marine Corps.

Without clearer imagery, I think it's difficult to answer precisely which weapon was actually used. It's possible (but again inconclusive) that they are M4s - it may have been what the prop department had on hand, and because it is not a military or historical piece, they used them because they were "close enough". Unless they're going for absolutely accuracy, Hollywood prop departments tend to use what they have.

<sub>An example aside, consider *Timecop* and *Stargate: Atlantis*. Two weapons modified for the film, one of them very distinctive, show up on an entirely unrelated television series. It's highly likely somebody in the prop department was asked for a "futuristic" gun and said "How 'bout this one we already have?"</sub>

Comment: Because the (whole) episode is indoor/at night so I can't provide the clearer images, but you're right, it must be the 723 model. Thanks for that IMFD site. That would be useful.

Answer (score -4):

Short barreled AR15 rifles have been round since Vietnam. The M4 wasn't introduced until 1994. The CAR-15 and it's derivatives have been around since the 60's.

Comment: So your answer is that the gun in the screenshot is a CAR-15, not an M4? Could you make it clearer? Right now it just looks like you're repeating the premise of the question (i.e. that the M4 is an anachronism).